# Matrix Calculation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, determinants

Could someone help me solve this problem in Matlab..
Suppose I have this Matriks

```
 A=[2-x 5    
    2   3-x ]
```

where det(A)=0;

So, it can be written as : (to alculate the detrminant)

```
   (2-x * 3-x)-(5*2)=0
```

But In matlab I cannot put x before I define it..

There will be an error :

```
 Undefined function or variable 'x'.
```

Please help me!!
I'm not allowed to use det function from Matlab!!!

Comment: You need the 'Symbolic' Toolbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to say matlab that `x` is a symbolic variable:

```
syms x;
A=[2-x, 5; 2, 3-x];
solve(det(A) == 0)
```

Comment: Hii,, yeah I know there is Det function.. But Im not alowed to use it!!! I have to calculate determinant manually with (2-x * 3-x)-(5*2)=0.. But I always get error in Matlab because the X variable never defined before...After I calculate manually then I will use matlab root function.. Do u know how to multipley (2-5) with (3-x)???

Comment: define the variable as symbolic. `syms x; detA = (2-x)*(3-x)-5*2; solve(detA == 0);` Don't forget the parentheis or the expression will be wrong as in your question.